# Data is being stored incorrectly when written from Datatable to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, date

I am using the following code to create a datatable and then write back to an SQL database.

As you can see I convert my date value to type 103, so it should be dd/mm/yyyy.

If I view the datatable it is in the correct format, but when it writes back to the SQL database the value is being stored as yyyy-mm-dd

Code to create datatable (dt):

```
                    Dim conn9 As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
                    With conn9
                        .ConnectionString = "server=inlt01\SQLEXPRESS; database=DaisyBilling; integrated security=yes"
                        .Open()
                    End With

                    Dim cmd9 As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
                    With cmd9
                        .CommandText = "SELECT [CustomerCLI], LEFT(MIN(DATENAME(MONTH,[CallDate])),3) AS [Short Month Name], [CustomerLookup], [CustomerName], ROUND (SUM ([SalesPrice]),2) as [Sum of Buy Price], ROUND (SUM ([Sell Price]),2) as [Sum of Sell Price],[Tariff Lookup],[Qty],[LineDescription],[Billingmonth], (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(MAX ([CallDate]))-1),MAX ([CallDate])),103)) AS FromDate, (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,MAX ([CallDate])))),DATEADD(mm,1,MAX ([CallDate]))),103)) as ToDate FROM [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[" + TextBox1.Text + "] GROUP BY [CustomerCLI], [CustomerLookup],[CustomerName],[Tariff Lookup],[Qty],[LineDescription],[Billingmonth] ORDER BY [CustomerLookup]"
                        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                        .CommandTimeout = 30
                        .Connection = conn9
                    End With
                    Dim dt As New DataTable
                    dt.Load(cmd9.ExecuteReader)

                    With ViewBillForm.DataGridView1
                        .AutoGenerateColumns = True
                        .DataSource = dt
                    End With

                    cmd9.Dispose()
                    cmd9 = Nothing
```

Code to export datatable to SQL dB:

```
                    Dim conn2 As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
                    With conn2
                        .ConnectionString = "server=inlt01\SQLEXPRESS; database=MasterBill; integrated security=yes"
                        .Open()
                    End With

                    Using copy As New SqlBulkCopy(conn2)

                        copy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.DaisyCallsCurrentBill"
                        copy.WriteToServer(dt)

                    End Using

                    conn.Close()
                    conn.Dispose()
```

How can I get my value to store correctly when being written back to the database?

Thanks

Comment: Format your code to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should handle how the date is presented and shouldn't really be concerned with how the data is stored by SQL. Since you want your date represented in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, set a display format on your respective grid column. For example:

```
DataGridView1.Columns("FromDate").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

This will keep the data stored in your `DataTable` (which is pushed back to SQL) as a date, but present it in the format you want.

A bit more info might explain why you are actually getting the error:

SQL Server always represents date in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format. You may have noticed that you can actually write a value to a date field using something like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET DateField = '2014-11-10' -- This will store a date for Nov 10, 2104.
WHERE Id = 132
```

However if you were to try to update the same date in either `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy` then SQL can get "confused" as it doesn't know if the format you want is the former or the latter.

```
-- This is dangerous.
UPDATE MyTable
SET DateField = '11/10/2014' -- Is this Nov 10, 2014 or Oct 11, 2014?
WHERE Id = 132
```